# Calculate elapsed years (XXXX format) with javascript in a self executing function

Tags: javascript, function, date

Hi I want to create an elapse time calculator between 2 years the actual one and a past one (input from the user) using date methods inside a self executing function.
The result must show only the difference between the year for example 10 if the past year is 2015.
This the program I wrote which does not run at all

```
(function getActualYear() {
        var dt = new Date();
        var actualYear = dt.getFullYear();
        return actualYear;
    }

    function getPastYear() {
        var dt = new Date()
        var pastYear = dt.setFullYear();
        return pastYear;
    }

    function getElapseTime(actualYear, pastYear) {
        elapseTime = actualYear - pastYear;
        return elapseTime;
    }

    function displayElapseTime() {
        alert("The elapse time is " + getElapseTime(getYear() - getPastYear()) + "Years");
    }

    function init() {
        displayElapseTime();
    }
})();
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: The code as it is right now in your question, isn't valid JS. Use a proper IDE, and have a look at the syntax errors it returns.

Comment: Neither description or code make sense. User inputs date how? Query string? Input element? Self-executing? On page load? On year entry?

Answer (score 0):

The line `var pastYear = dt.setFullYear();` is where the issue is. `setFullYear()` expects you to put a integer value in the `()` to set the year for that date object.
So the `getPastYearMethod()` should look like:

```
function getPastYear(date){
var dt= new Date(date)
var year = dt.getFullYear();
return pastYear;
}
```

The reason is, how should the method know which past year you are referring to? You need to tell it.

Also if the user is passing just a year then really all you need to do is get the int value of the current year and subtract it from the int value of the user's input, there's no need to turn into a date.